# Getting mouse position from a custom nsview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to get the mouse location relative to the nsview.

There are at least two methods that I know of:

```
NSPoint mousePosition = [self.window convertScreenToBase:[NSEvent mouseLocation]];
```

And

```
NSPoint mousePosition = [self.window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
```

The problem with both of those methods is that self.view is null. I'm adding this view from a view controller that itself was added by another view controller. I would like to know if it's possible to get the toplevel window starting from a nsview that can be many levels below.

Edit: of course I can use:

```
NSWindow *window = [self valueForKeyPath:@"delegate.delegate.view.window"];
```

But there must be a better way.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand why you say ‘self.view is null’ (a non-existent view cannot be added to a window) and what do you mean by top level window (a view belongs to a single window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would like to know if it's possible to get the toplevel window starting from a nsview that can be many levels below.**

Sure:

```
NSView *view = …;
NSWindow *window = [view window];
```

Comment: For some reasons that doesn't work for me, [view window] is null.

Comment: You’d said that ‘self.view is null’. Is `self` a subclass of `NSViewController`? Are you programatically creating a view in `-loadView` or is it loaded from a nib file? If you’re loading it from a nib file, are you sure you’ve set the `view` outlet?

Comment: [view window] is null, view is correctly set. I've solved by using some delegates.

Comment: @Oscar If `[view window]` is `nil` but `view` isn’t, this means that your view hasn’t been added to a window (i.e., it hasn’t been added as the subview of a superview that belongs to the window view hierarchy). If that’s the case, you need to get the window reference via other means — for instance, your solution of using a delegate.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: the following is not necessary, as pointed out in the comments, `view.window` will return the window (if any) from anywhere in the hierarchy.**

<del>This question is quite old, but if anyone ends up here looking up if it's possible to get the toplevel window starting from a nsview that can be many levels below.</del>

<del>I came up with this in Swift 4:</del>

```
extension NSView {

    /// Returns the first window referenced by self or any of the parent views in the hierarchy
    var parentWindow: NSWindow? {
        if self.window != nil {
            return self.window
        }
        return self.superview?.parentWindow
    }
}
```

Comment: Why to make it complicated. A view will always return the associated window if its displayed on the screen.

Comment: I thought that only the view set as content view of the window would have the `self.window` property set. If this is not the case, but every view in the hierarchy has `self.window` set, then yes this is useless :) Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, any view in a window view hierarchy will have the window property pointing to the window. Its a great feature I am using many times.